# gvim can be really slow to display the last typed character in VirtualBox. How do I fix that issue?

Tags: gvim, cursor-movement

While working in an Ubuntu VirtualBox (host is also Ubuntu), gvim is being really slow at showing the last character I just typed, or, when I move the cursor up/down/left/right, it also takes 1 to 2 seconds before the last position is shown. Everything else is fast as usual, it's only that last small glitch that makes it really hard to use.

I found [this post (Sometimes gvim doesn't show character typed immediately)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28682/sometimes-gvim-doesnt-show-character-typed-immediately), which mentions maps.

I also found [this post of stackoverflow (Why is Vim so slow?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644682/why-is-vim-so-slow), and tried with:

```
gvim -u NONE
```

to make sure that the syntax, maps (as mentioned above), the 'cc' variable, etc. would not be the culprit. The issue persists (although I can feel it's a tad faster, probably because of the syntax removal).

My feel would be that vim/gvim makes use of a timer to know when to display that last character and that timer is probably in the low ms (maybe 25ms) and a VirtualBox does not have that kind of ability (I tested with my own software a while back and it's just horrendously bad).

Would there be a way to remove that 1 to 2 second delay that I missed?

**Note:** When moving around with the mouse, I do not get the issue. The placement with a click is instantaneous.

---

**Update 1:** I tested with the `timeout` and `ttimeout` and the corresponding length of time to wait, `timeoutlen` and `ttimeoutlen`.

Here are the commands I tested with:

```
:set timeoutlen=10000
:set ttimeoutlen=10000
:set timeout!
:set ttimeout!
```

and the issue is still there. Fast while I type up until the last character. Only in `gvim`...

**Update 2:** Note that happens with ANY character. It could be a space, a-z, 0-9, any usual character. The last one I type takes about 1s to appear. It has nothing to do (I would imagine) with the mapping capability. Although it does seem related to one of those delays because if I type another character, it shows the previous one instantaneously. And as mentioned above, it also happens when I use the arrow keys (Up, Down, Left, Right). It will move quickly to the line/character just before the one select. That last one will be shown about 1s later... so I often end up one line too high or too low.

**Update 3:** Oh... the previous changes made me think that maybe it has something to do with the blinking cursor, so I tried this command:

```
set guicursor+=a:blinkon0
```

and interestingly enough, while I type, I never see the last character. Once I'm done typing, the last character never actually appears. So the blinking cursor actually helps showing that last character!

Comment: The way you wrote your question makes it sound like a VirtualBox issue. Do other applications show similar lags or is it just gVim?

Comment: @Friedrich I don't see it in the console or the browsers which are nearly the only other two things I use pretty consistently in the VM.

Comment: To find out if it is related to `map` I would issue the following Vim command `:set timeoutlen=10000` if the delay for the last character increase to 10 sec we know it is related to mapping. You could also issue `:set ttimeoutlen=10000`.  Could you try that and let us know the result? Could you tell us which keys led to the problem? Is it in insert mode or in normal mode?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Thank you for the info. I tried those and it did not seem to help. I even turned off the `timeout` and `ttimeout` flags (`:set [t]timeout!`) and it still waiting about 1s to display the last thing I typed or the cursor after arrow movements.

Comment: And when you do the opposite (increase the values) is the problem getting worst?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I tried both ways, large numbers, small numbers, on/off, no difference. However, the non-blinking cursor is an interesting one since nothing appears when not blinking.